# Failed to open dir : Bad file descriptor

Tags: php, directory

I face this problem. When i try to open the file list in other server which is 10.200.4.202. The error below appears.

When I try using a local host, the file list can be viewed normally. I think the code is not the error but the server setting is not right.

I used IIS 10.0, PHP 7.3.15

**This is what appears on web**

```
status[parsererror] content[SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0]
```

**and this is the error in f12**

```
Warning:  
opendir(\\10.200.4.202\y\1.InspCheckSheet_PDF\log,\\10.200.4.202\y\1.InspCheckSheet_PDF\log): Access is denied. (code: 5) in C:\PGMPIS_Web\public_html\ics_filing\loglist_sub.php on line 68


Warning:  
opendir(\\10.200.4.202\y\1.InspCheckSheet_PDF\log): failed to open dir: Bad file descriptor in C:\PGMPIS_Web\public_html\ics_filing\loglist_sub.php 
    on line 68

    {"querytime":"2020-05-14  09:58:50","other_status":"ERR","errmsg":""}
```

**Here's the code**

```
<?php

    $dir_log = '\\\\10.200.4.202\\y\\1.InspCheckSheet_PDF\\log';

    require_once 'Log.php';
    $log    = Log::factory('file', 'log/okaspe.log',    'loglist_sub');     //$log->log('teeeeest!');

    //$type = $_REQUEST['type'];                    


try{
    // Set query_time
    $emsg = "";
    $now = new DateTime();
    $res['querytime'] = $now->format('Y-m-d  H:i:s');
    //$res['querytime'] = $now->format('Y-m-d  g:i:s A');



    // Obtain log file name list → $fn[]
    $cnt = $pos = 0;
    unset($fn);         // clear $fn for safety

    if( $dir = opendir($dir_log) ) {                            // add @ infront of opendir by asyraf
        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false ) {
            $pos = strpos ($file, 'main_');                     // faster than preg_match() for simple search

            if( $pos !== false  &&  $pos == 0) {
                $cnt++;
                $fn[] = $file;
            }
        } 

        closedir($dir);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Obtain Log File List failed......"); 
    }


    // sort in descending order
    rsort($fn);             //$log->log( print_r($fn, true) );


    //set response
    $res['list'] = $fn;
    $res['cnt']  = $cnt;




} catch( Exception $e ) {
    // Functional Err exception
    $res["other_status"] = "ERR";
    $res["errmsg"      ] = $emsg;

    $log->log($e->getMessage(), PEAR_LOG_ERR);                  // logging


} finally {
    //DB disconnect  (absolutely and always)
    $pdo = null;


    // Response in Json
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $json = json_encode( $res );            //$log->log($json, PEAR_LOG_ERR);
    echo $json;


}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I would first double-check which user is your PHP running as, and then make sure that this user actually has access to the network share.

Comment: I already check the access ability to the required server. There are password protected, eventually it can access the file well